# switch db instance in runtime

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

There are two mongo clusters (front and back). Front cluster is used by service and back cluster is being updated with new data. It is similar to double buffer schema in graphics.

Also there is a service (tomcat instances with webservice inside it) that utilize currently active cluster. And this service should work during switch process. Already started units of work should complete using single cluster to ensure result consistency and all new units of work should use new cluster.

How can these clusters be switched? Probably there some tools, libraries that implement that?

I can envision two ways:

- implement proxy (similar to `mongos`) and route services through that proxy. Proxy uses one of clusters. Proxy needs to know to what unit of work query belongs. I thought to split `requestId` into two parts, one to identify unit of work and one to indentify query inside that unit of work. This approach also requires service modification to tune `requestId`.
- another way is to modify service itself. There will be several `MongoClient` instances and single proxy that implement cluster switching.

Any other suggestions?